# Create file from variable value with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, filenames

I would like to create a file from variable value with spaces.

- Variable Value: `Los Angeles`
- Create Filename: `"Los Angeles.txt"`

Script Snippet:

```
ProjectSite=" Los Angeles"
fname=`echo ${ProjectSite} | sed 's,^ *,,; s, *$,,'`".txt"
touch "${fname}"
```

Current Output:

```
'Los Angeles.txt'
```

File is created along with single quote.

Required Output:

```
Los Angeles.txt
```

Comment: It's not really causing trouble here, but you should double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "${ProjectSite}"` instead of just `echo ${ProjectSite}). I'd also recommend using `$( )` instead of backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name is correct as is. It doesn't have single quotes; that's simply how `ls` displays it. You can use `ls -N` to tell `ls` not to quote file names with special characters:

```
❯ touch 'Los Angeles.txt'
❯ ls
'Los Angeles.txt'
❯ ls -N
Los Angeles.txt
```